# Basis free way to show $\alpha(V,-)=\alpha(W,-)=0$ implies $\alpha([V,W],-)=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given a 2-form $\alpha$, I want to show that, if $X$ and $Y$ are vector fields such that $\alpha(X,Z)=\alpha(Y,Z)=0$ for all vector fields $Z$, then $\alpha([X,Y],Z)=0$ for all vector fields $Z$.

Since I had no better ideas, I just expanded everything out in a local chart, and I think it works. However, is there a nicer proof that sheds more light?

---

Edit:
After seeing Jack Lee's answer below, I realized I forgot the crucial hypothesis that $\alpha$ is closed. I think that you can use $\alpha=d\beta$ locally, and $d\beta(X,Y)=X(\beta(Y))-Y(\beta(X))-\beta([X,Y])$ generally. Then, using the identities
\begin{align*}
d\beta(X,Z)=X(\beta(Z))-Z(\beta(X))-\beta([X,Z])&=0\\
d\beta(Y,Z)=Y(\beta(Z))-Z(\beta(Y))-\beta([Y,Z])&=0,
\end{align*}
we can expand out 
\begin{align*}
d\beta([X,Y],Z)=[X,Y]\beta(Z)-Z(\beta([X,Y]))-\beta([[X,Y],Z]),
\end{align*}
replace $[X,Y]\beta(Z)$ with $X(Y(\beta(Z)))-Y(X(\beta(Z)))$, and apply the identities above to move the $Z$ to the outside. Also, we can use the Jacobi identity on the last term $\beta([[X,Y],Z])=\beta([X,[Y,Z]])+\beta([Y,[Z,X]])$ and again applying the identities above, I think everything ends up cancelling out. I don't know if there is supposed to be an easier way (at least this doesn't involve a bunch of indices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Take $\alpha$ to be the following $2$-form on $\mathbb R^4$ with coordinates $(w,x,y,z)$:
$$
\alpha = dz\wedge dw - x \,dy \wedge dw,
$$
and let $X,Y$ be the vector fields 
$$ 
X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \qquad 
Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}.
$$
Then $\iota_X\alpha = \iota_Y\alpha =0$, but $[X,Y] = \partial/\partial z$ and $\iota_{[X,Y]}\alpha = dw \ne 0$. (Here $\iota_X$ represents [interior multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product) by $X$.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the assumption that $\alpha$ is closed, and I think now that using locally $\alpha(X,Y)=d\beta(X,Y)=X(\beta(Y))-Y(\beta(X))-\beta([X,Y])$ works. I still need to see where I fooled myself earlier though. Also, how did you suspect the question as stated was false, and how did you come up with the counterexample?

Comment: I don't quite see how that formula will do it. But there's a similar but more complicated formula for the [exterior derivative of a $2$-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#Invariant_formula), which does yield the result you want more or less immediately.

Comment: How did I come up with it? The condition $\iota_X\alpha=0$ is reminiscent of the $1$-form characterization of a tangent distribution, and the condition that $[X,Y]$ belong to the distribution when $X$ and $Y$ do would say that the distribution is involutive. So I took the simplest example of a noninvolutive distribution, defined by $dz - x\,dy$ on $\mathbb R^3$, and then wedged with $dw$ to get a $2$-form.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your edit above, suggesting a way to use the formula for $d$ of a $1$-form. That might well work. But I think it's much easier to use the formula for $d$ of a $2$-form.